# Moving/dragging a metabox removes TinyMCE's content

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, tinymce

I added a TinyMCE editor to my plugin settings page, but once I move (drag) the metabox, editor's content get lost. (the TinyMCE editor is completely not editable until refresh)

Here is how I added TinyMCE editor:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_tinymce_editor' );

function add_tinymce_editor() {
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_tiny_mce' ) ) {
        add_filter('teeny_mce_before_init', create_function( '$a', '
            $a["mode"] = "textareas";
            $a["editor_selector"] = "";
            $a["plugins"] = "safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker";
            return $a;')
        );

        wp_tiny_mce( true );
    }
}
```

Any ideas what can cause this bug and how to prevent/fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with radio buttons losing their status when I dragged a metabox on a settings page.

I hacked together a workaround and posted it as a reply to the original wordpress trac ticket
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972#comment:4

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be caused by jQuery UI:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972

Comment: Haha, this is the bug I reported, but I wasn't sure that it is the same with TinyMCE, so currently we can't do anything with that, right?

Comment: You can try to find a workaround. If you find something, do share.